# Read XML Value in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to extract an XML value from a SQL Server column and put it into a SQL statement. My problem is that the documentation I've found doesn't explain how to do this if there are spaces or `""` in the XML path.

I'm trying to extract the `value` property in the XML shown here (there is no namespace in the XML). The SQL Server column is called `Settings`:

```
<properties>
   <settings hwid="stream:0.0.0">
      <setting typeid="78622C19-58AE-40D4-8EEA-17351F4273B6">
         <name>Codec</name>
         <value>4</value>
      </setting>
   </settings>
</properties>
```

Comment: What is your database and its version?

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, it's Express 2014.

Comment: Is it MS SQL Server?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Sorry Yirzhak, yes it is.  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64)   Sep  7 2018 01:37:51   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Ok. We are getting closer. What about ##1-3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPENXML` to retrieve data from xml, first create procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetXmlValueProc
    @xml NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @hdoc INT;

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xml;

    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(50);
    SELECT  value
    FROM
        OPENXML(@hdoc, '/properties/settings/setting', 2)
        WITH
        (
            value VARCHAR(100)
        );

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc;
END
GO
```

And call procedure in this way:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)='<properties><settings hwid="stream:0.0.0"><setting typeid="78622C19-58AE-40D4-8EEA-17351F4273B6"><name>Codec</name><value>4</value></setting></settings></properties>'

EXEC dbo.GetXmlValueProc @xml
```

Even you can make procedure more generic and pass the xml path to get data.

Comment: Thanks Saeed, I was able to get the data required with this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any spaces in your XML. If you mean the various attributes, such as `hwid`, those are parsed separately from the node names. You can select those by prefacing with `@`.

I assume the type of the `value` node is `int`, if not you can change it below:

```sql
SELECT
    t.Settings.value('(/properties/settings/setting/value)[1]', 'int'),
    t.Settings.value('(/properties/settings/setting/@typeid)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
    t.Settings.value('(/properties/settings/@hwid)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM myTable t
```

---

For reference, if you ever did have a node with a space in it: it would be encoded `&#32;` and a double-quote as `&#34;`

Comment: Hi Charlieface.  I removed some of the XML as it's a big file.  There are other setting sections which are all called the same thing except the hwid and typeid parts.  Is there a way I can include that in the XML select?

Comment: Have edited. If you want to break out a single XML blob into separate rows, please be clearer. Include more of the XML (not the whole thing, just a sample structure) and what info you want from it